# Resolving unstated -llapack dependency issue on Solaris

Tags: r, solaris, rcpp, cran

I have released an `R` package on `CRAN` which depends on the successful compilation of some `RcppArmadillo` code. The package built correctly and with no notes on all the test systems that I tried ([CRAN comments here if interested](https://github.com/Chris1221/goldi/blob/master/cran-comments.md)), however, the CRAN checks fail on `solaris-sparc` and are unable to load a dependency on `solaris-x86`.

[See here for CRAN checks](http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/web/checks/check_results_goldi.html).

The reason for the error is given as `ld: fatal: library -llapack: not found` (from [goldi-00install.html](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-sparc/goldi-00install.html)).

In my `Makevars` and `Makevars.win`, I have stated `-llapack` in `PKG_LIBS`, which I thought was sufficient.

`PKG_LIBS= -Wsign-compare -llapack` in both.

However, I'm unsure how to declare this dependency for Solaris. Is there a separate `Makevars` that I must write, or there a different location that I must state the dependency?

I have read the [relevant section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) of the "Writing R Extensions" manual, and suspect that I may have to declare `$(LLAPACK_LIBS)` in `PKG_LIBS`, but have no way of testing it on a solaris platform. Is this the correct path to follow?

Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated.

---

[Package on Github](https://github.com/chris1221/goldi)

[Package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/goldi/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line in [src/Makevars](https://github.com/Chris1221/goldi/blob/master/src/Makevars#L1) is just wrong. Don't do what you did:

```
PKG_LIBS= -Wsign-compare -llapack
```

do what we all do, *what the example package has* and the what the [*auto-generated package gets*](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/skeleton/Makevars#L1):

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

Believe us when we say that it just works.  I venture that among the two-hundred-ninenty-one (291 !!) packages on CRAN, essentially all use this.

And any who do not, like yours, simply do it wrong.  The above *dispatches to what R knows about LAPACK and its dependencies*.  Use it.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I was hoping I could catch you in person. This is my first voyage into `Rcpp` and I'm glad to be set straight. I'll change this and resubmit to CRAN. All the best.

Comment: Great, and congrats for getting it to CRAN in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I was quite excited. A bunch of my friends got screenshots of the index page about five minutes after it was put up.  Thanks again, hope you're having a nice day.